# Template.dynamic fails with Uncaught Error: {{#each}}

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

`{{> myTemp}}` works fine but `{{> Template.dynamic template="myTemp"}}` yields

> Uncaught Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values.

Not sure where to look

-- updated to add the each block --

```
{{#each this}}
      <section class="blog-post">
        {{#if isInRole 'mdblog-author'}}
          {{> blogControls }}
        {{/if}}
          <header>
              <h2><a href="{{pathFor route='blogPost'}}">{{title}}</a></h2>
                  <span class="info">{{_ "posted_by"}}<span class="author">{{author}}</span>
                      <time>{{mdBlogDate date}}</time>
                  </span>
          </header>
          <summary>
            {{{summary}}} <a href="{{pathFor route='blogPost'}}">{{_ "read_more"}}
              <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
          </summary>
      </section>
  {{else}}
      {{_ "waiting_for_posts"}}
  {{/each}}
```

Comment: can you show the #each loop with the helper var that you're iterating through?

Answer (score 0):

`this` is an object pointing to the data context, which is an object (or undefined, but if that were the case, it wouldn't throw an error). You can't iterate over objects.

You want to iterate over an array stored in your data context (naturally non-reactive) or a mongo cursor (reactive). If your goal is to iterate over each item in the data context, then it's as easy as turning an object's values into an array. I'm not sure exactly what your goal is, but you probably want to follow something like this:

```
 sampleDoc: function () {
    var valArr = [];
    for (var key in this) {
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        valArr.push(this[key]);
      }
    }
    return valArr;
 }
```

If you need the keys too, just create a key array & push `key` instead of `this[key]`
If you need reactivity, just stick a `.depend()` at the beginning.